# Override file icon in windows shell/explorer

Tags: c#, file, shell, icons, windows-explorer

Is there a way to override the icon and/or preview of a specific file format (my own) in Windows Explorer using C#? My files are xml files that contain a base-64 image, I'd like to display this image in Explorer as the file icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a [thumbnail shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144118(VS.85).aspx). There's an [older MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx) that addresses writing shell extensions in general (though it doesn't specifically address thumbnail shell extensions).

Note that this was not possible pre-.NET 4.0 (hence the editor's note on the MSDN article). I originally thought that you would have to target .NET 4.0 for it to work, but according to [Peter Ritchie's blog post on the subject](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/11/12/net-4-0-evolving-net-development.aspx), you could target any version (.NET 4.0 just has to be *installed*).